# I can't use my label in codebehind?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, android-layout

I am trying to code an android app using `Visual Studio`.
I have looked through several tutorials but I just can't figure out why I can't edit my `label` within the codebehind file.

For example I want the `label` to disappear when I `click` the `button`. I declared an `Eventhandler` that works just fine, but I can't use my Label in my
**C# Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="LblName1"  Text="Hallo"/>
        <Button x:Name="CmdButton1" Text="Folge mir zum Regelbuch" Margin="0,400,0,4" Clicked="CmdButton1_Click"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I thought I would be able to use it since I declared it with `x:name=""` but I just can't reach it. I am a bloody beginner so I am sorry for the dump question...

Edit:

The Xaml-Code is contained in Mainpage.xaml and I want to access the label from Mainpage.xaml.cs if that is enough information. My simple C# Code lookes like that:

```
namespace App1
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CmdRegelbuch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblName1.IsVisible=false;
    }
}
}
```

I hope this extended my question enough.

Comment: Where is the XAML from your question located (in which control/XAML file) ? And where in your program do you try to access the label (name of class/.cs file containing the code relevant to the label); and what does the code look like? Please **edit and expand your question** with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow Maxam,

Have you set the DataContext correctly?
Not the cleanest solution but a quick way to test it is to add
`DataContext = this;`
right after `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: "DataContext is not available in this context"

Comment: okay since this is xamarin you have to use BindingContext instead of DataContext

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the code provided is from *MyUserControl.xaml*, then you would have a CmdButton1_Click in your *MyUserControl.xaml.cs* (code behind) file.

There you should set the visiblity of the label.

```
private void CmdButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LblName1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: It is not able to reach my label in the code behind file. (I edited my question to clarify where my XAML came from)